# A good way to let the callback remember some info (C++)

Tags: c++, callback

I used a callback in my program, and this callback will be called repeatedly, so I want to use some method to store the current info, so that he can remember where he is. I want to create a  class, and use some static members to store them, but I think it is not good...I want some suggestions, thanks a lot!!

Actually, I prefer to use structure or class, and I give a simple example for my idea.

```
callback(parameters)
{
   A* a->setcounter(record current value);
   A* a->getcounter(get current value);
   A* a->addcounter(current value ++);
   A* a->calculate(do some calculation with values);
}
```

What confused me is that I should first create a object of class A, but I don't want to do this, so I choose to use static member, but I think there should be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Have a parameter in your callback function be a context object, that is some instance of a struct type or class that wraps state information that is useful to the callback function to identify what the state of the program is.  The callback function can predicate on this state to know what operations to perform.

Comment: Is it like what I wrote in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason static variables in the function won't do it?

```
int my_callback(int i)
{
    static int my_int;
    if (i != -1) my_int = i;

    return my_int;
}
```

In this example, passing any value to my_callback will assign that value to the callback's static variable, except for `-1`, which will return the current value without assigning to it.

Comment: Omaha's solution is probably preferable, but this will work if you can't get your caller to pass things to the callback.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a functor, i.e. an object of a class that defines an `operator()`, you can use that in the same way as a function (e.g. in the place of the callback function you use now), but in data members of the class you can store state information. Something along the lines of this:

```
class CallbackObject {
  int _state_information;
public:
  CallbackObject():_state_information(0) {}

  void operator()(int some_data_to_process) {
    /* ..process data.. */

    ++_state_information; // Update internal state
  }
};
```

Then objects of this class can be used in the same way as a callback function.

---

However, if you can use C++11, there is a particularly convenient way to achieve a similar effect, using *capturing lambdas:*

```
#include <iostream>

/* This is our "backend" that calls the callback
   function: */
template <typename Callback>
void process(int data, Callback callback) {
  callback(data);
}

int main()
{
  /* State information: */
  int num_calls = 0;

  /* Here we define the callback function as a lambda: */
  auto callback = [&num_calls](int data) { ++num_calls; };

  /* Have it called a few times: */
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
    process(i,callback);

  std::cout << "Callback was called " << num_calls << " times." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The `callback` variable in the `main` function stores the lambda function. `[&num_calls]` means that the integer variable `num_calls` is captured as reference, so any change made to its value when the lambda is called will directly affect the original variable `num_calls`. Hence you can use captured references like `num_calls` (which of course may of a more complex type, or more than one variable) to store and update state information.

Comment: Good idea, but the callback's type and how it should be called have already been defined by others, so I can just modify the way of store state information in it.

Comment: @CJAN.LEE In that case could you please describe (using precise C++ syntax) what the type of the callback is supposed to be?